# How to pass header from stdin or local file into remote curl?

Tags: ssh, curl, stdin

The following `curl` command works as expected:

```
$ curl -H @- -vso/dev/null http://www.example.com <<<"Foo:Bar"
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.example.com/
...
> Accept: */*
> Foo:Bar
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

since I can see my custom header (`Foo:Bar`), but it doesn't work when running via `ssh`:

```
$ ssh user@localhost curl -H @- -vso/dev/null http://www.example.com <<<"Foo:Bar"
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.example.com/
...
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
...
```

I can confirm that the stdin works on the remote by:

```
$ ssh user@localhost cat <<<"Foo:Bar"
Foo:Bar
```

My goal is to pass the headers from stdin or local file (not from the variable) into remote `curl`.

And I'm not quite sure why the above doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

The argument in `@filename` style for `-H` has been added in 7.55.0 (`man curl`).

> `-H`/`--header <header/@file>`
>
> Starting in 7.55.0, this option can take an argument in `@filename` style, which then adds a  header  for each line in the input file. Using `@-` will make curl read the header file from stdin.

---

The problem with `ssh` happened because older `curl` version was used.

So basically two different versions of `curl` were involved.

```
$ which curl && curl --version
/usr/local/bin/curl
curl 7.59.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.3.0) libcurl/7.59.0 OpenSSL/1.0.2o zlib/1.2.11 libidn2/2.0.4
$ ssh user@localhost 'which curl && curl --version'
/usr/bin/curl
curl 7.54.0 (x86_64-apple-darwin17.0) libcurl/7.54.0 LibreSSL/2.0.20 zlib/1.2.11 nghttp2/1.24.0
```

So hardcoding the path to newer `/usr/local/bin/curl` (v7.59/OpenSSL) it seems to work fine:

```
$ ssh user@localhost /usr/local/bin/curl -H @- -vso/dev/null http://www.example.com <<<"Foo:Bar"
```