# Curl : Read headers from a file and use them in a cURL command

Tags: curl, header-file

I have a bash script with the following curl command :

```
curl -v -X GET https://example.com -H ~/Desktop/headers.txt -o ~/Desktop/file.txt
```

When i run the bash script i am getting unothorized 401. Obviously i am not reading  the header file correctly. My header file looks like that "Authorization: Bearer 40bsafsdgds34234....". My curl version is 7.26

Comment: not sure if this might be the problem, but you should put the options before the URL: `curl [options] [URL...]`.

Comment: That's not the problem sadly. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-H` option reads header information per default from the argument (text), not from files.

Since `curl 7.55` you can use `-H @file` to read from a file.

---

For old versions you need a small script, something like this:

```
curl $(xargs -a headers.txt -I{} printf '-H "%s" ' "{}") URL
```

Some Links:

- [Related question on U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/441359/how-to-pass-header-from-stdin-or-local-file-into-remote-curl)
- [Duplicate question from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12661159/curl-read-headers-from-file)

---

**Alternative**:

Create the config file including `-H "..."`:

```
-H "Authorization: bearer token"
-H "Another header"
```

and use `-K/--config <config file>` option.

or automatically with your original file via `sed`:

```
curl -K <(sed -r 's/^(.*)$/-H "\1"/' headers.txt) URL
```

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trial and error i found out that this works for me

```
curl -v -X GET https://example.com -H "$(cat ~/Desktop/headers.txt)" -o ~/Desktop/file.txt
```